# Не могу сделать переключение на PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, settings

Код транзакции:

```
SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,settingsFragment, getString(R.string.settings_fragment))
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .commit();
```

Код класса SettingsFragment:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_layout);
}
```

В методе replace ошибка - 2 параметр, оижадется Fragment а получает Settings fragment
Текст ошибки:

> Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.*****.android.*******.SettingsFragment', required: 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment'

Как пофиксить?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у вас SettingsFragment наследован от PreferenceFragment, который в свою очередь наследован от Fragment из саппорт-библиотек(appcompat), и работать с ним нужно с помощью оттуда же полученного менеджера фрагмента, который можно получить методом getSupportFragmentManager

Comment: Не помогло, правки в вопросе сделал